# Relative paths in an AutoCAD script (.scr)

Tags: autocad-scripts

As I am using LT 2024, have limited programming skills and need to open and close a number of files I am trying to use a script (.scr) file not a lisp or VBA.
The script below does some basic cleaning of files exported from GIS and saves the DXFs as DWGs but I would like this to use relative paths (relative to the working file) so I can avoid changing the paths for each project.
Is there a way in can set the paths based on the current open file?

`_.open "T:\DXF output\Canopies and Boles.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\Canopies and Boles.dwg" Y _.close _.open "T:\DXF output\LabelLines.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\LabelLines.dwg" Y _.close _.open "T:\DXF output\LabelText.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\LabelText.dwg" Y _.close _.open "T:\DXF output\LabelWhiteOuts.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\LabelWhiteOuts.dwg" Y _.close _.open "T:\DXF output\RPAs.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\RPAs.dwg" Y _.close _.open "T:\DXF output\Tree Markers.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\Tree Markers.dwg" Y _.close _.open "T:\DXF output\Zones Boles Canopies.dxf" _.Zoom E _.PURGE all * N _.save LT2018 "T:\DXF output\Zones Boles Canopies.dwg" Y _.close`

I tried lisps and VBA but lisps would need to be nested inside a script and VBA isn't available on LT 2024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AutoLISP `strcat` function to concatenate your filenames with the current drawing path by referencing the value of the `DWGPREFIX` system variable, which will return the path of the current drawing (with a trailing path delimiter), e.g.:

```lisp
(strcat (getvar 'dwgprefix) "Canopies and Boles.dxf")
```

Comment: I assume that I can replace the file name (Canopies and Boles) with a variable fed to the lisp so the same lisp can be used for each DXF

Comment: Yes - just ensure that the variable is defined in each drawing that you process (as LISP variables are defined in the document namespace).